# Method name conflicts in Moose roles

Tags: perl, oop, moose

What I would like to achieve is to create a Moose class that imports several roles. This is something I've been doing for years with no issues, though I am currently stuck on why the simple example below will generate method name conflicts.

```
package logrole;

use Moose::Role;
use POSIX;
use namespace::autoclean;

package otherrole;

use Moose::Role;
use File::Temp;
use namespace::autoclean;

package myclass;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
with 'logrole', 'otherrole'; 

package main;

use strict;
use warnings;
use myclass;
```

Running this gives:

```
Due to method name conflicts in roles 'logrole' and 'otherrole', the methods 'SEEK_CUR', 'SEEK_END', and 'SEEK_SET' must be implemented or excluded by 'myclass' at /home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.1/lib/site_perl/5.22.1/x86_64-linux/Moose/Exporter.pm line 419
Moose::with('logrole', 'otherrole') called at roles.pl line 29
```

According to the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Spec/Role.pod) you can exclude method names when consuming a role like so:

```
package logrole;

use Moose::Role;
use POSIX;
use namespace::autoclean;

package otherrole;

use Moose::Role;
use File::Temp;
use namespace::autoclean;

package myclass;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
with 'logrole', 'otherrole' => { -excludes => ["SEEK_CUR", "SEEK_END", "SEEK_SET" ] };

package main;

use strict;
use warnings;
use myclass;
```

This solves the name conflicts, but the problem with this solution is that trying to import `POSIX` in `otherrole` generates hundreds of name conflicts, so the fix of excluding all these in the module `myclass` seems very messy.

How can I import (or write) these roles to avoid the method name conflicts?

Comment: you could have included the names you were having issues with to make the is easy to replicate. This is not a verifiable example really

Comment: @bytepusher I posted the full output that shows the names (you have to scroll to the right). You can also see this in the second script.

Comment: Why the downvote? I provided the full script, link to the docs, a full working example, and full output with explanations and a clear question. Please comment if there is something you find missing.

Comment: `use namespace::autoclean;` is suppose to avoid this problem, but having everything in the same appears to be confusing it?

Comment: Note that POSIX exports like a hundred symbols. Why are you importing all of that?

Comment: @ikegami I'm only using POSIX for the `strftime` function. Specifically, `my $st = POSIX::strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', localtime);`. If I can get that done w/o POSIX I'd like it, but why imported method names are conflicting is still curious to me.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with my comment. Why do you import `SEEK_SET` when you only use `strftime`? Just importing what you need will speed things up.

Comment: As I've already mentioned, you simply need to get namespace::clean to do its job to solve your problem. Perhaps just adding curlies will do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps giving an empty list during import may solve these issues if using the fully qualified name instead of a function name works the same. Will test...

Comment: You're correct about the imports, I was importing things for no reason. Is namespace::clean a drop in replacement for namespace::autoclean? I was under the impression the latter was the preferred approach, or was (over the old "no Moose::Role" approach).

Comment: It will hide the problem, not solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[namespace::autoclean](http://p3rl.org/namespace::autoclean) doesn't remove methods, and it trusts [Class::MOP::Class](http://p3rl.org/Class::MOP::Class)'s `get_method_list` to return them. Confusingly, it returns all the constants from the POSIX module.

If you switch `namespace::autoclean` to [namespace::clean](http://p3rl.org/namespace::clean), the problems are gone.

Comment: Yes, this solves it. Swapping in namespace::clean in the role ("logrole" in the question) solves the conflict. Also, importing only the needed functions would be a much better approach as ikegami said, but I didn't know about this module so thanks for the explanation.